# What data access do JetBrains third-party plugins have?

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, jetbrains-ide, privacy

I'm considering installing a third-party plugin inside IntelliJ IDEA to add support for another programming language. I have to accept the following message. What access to my personal data does the developer of the plugin get?

The *vendor* is a single person and he does not provide information regarding data processing.

[image]

Comment: I want to know, is my code sent to the plugin maker?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but JetBrains mentions at the end, in the 

[User Agreement](https://www.jetbrains.com/legal/agreements/user.html#definitions) 
that

- > 2.14. "Personal Data" means any information relating to an identified or identifiable natural person.

JetBrains further explains what personal data means to them in 

[Personal Data](https://www.jetbrains.com/legal/agreements/user.html#personal-data) and [Why We Collect Data and What We Collect](https://www.jetbrains.com/company/privacy.html#why-we-collect-data-and-what-we-collect).

Jetbrains how ever explicitly states in this section 

[THIRD-PARTY SOFTWARE](https://www.jetbrains.com/legal/agreements/user.html#third-party-software), that it will not be held responsible for Third party software.

Comment: So, "7.2. For the above purposes, JetBrains may collect, among other things, your IP address, JetBrains Account username, JetBrains Account password, first name, last name, email address, and subscription information." Does it make sense though that they get the password?

Comment: @Sudix the p/w doesn't really matter since it would be salted and obfuscated to the holder (they see the hash, not the real p/w). What bothers me is that they have my personal email, which would ID you throughout the internet and build a profile on that. Nothing new, yet very concerning with the current geo political scenery atm.